# Show that there is a Lebesgue measurable subset with measure $a$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $A\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ has positive Lebesgue measure, then for each $0\leq a<m(A)$ there is a Lebesgue measurable $E\subset A$ with $m(E)=a$.

We have that

$E\subset A \Rightarrow m(E)\leq m(A)$

and

$m(A)>a$

How can we conclude that $m(E)=a$ ??

Answer (score 4):

Define $f(t)=m(B_t(0)\cap A)$ where $B_t(0)$ is the open ball of radius $t$ centered at the origin. Show that $f$ is continuous and use the intermediate value theorem.

Define $E_t=A\cap B_t(0)$. Then the measure of $E_t$ is $f(t)$. $f(0)=0$ and $f(t)$ approaches $m(A)$ as $t$ approaches infinity, so for any $a<m(A)$ there exists a $t$ such that $m(E_t)=a$. $E_t$ therefore satisfies the condition.

To show continuity, choose $t_0>0$. We know that the volume of a ball is a continuous increasing function of the radius. Suppose the volume of a ball of radius $t$ is $V(t)$. We are given $\epsilon$ and we want to find $\delta$ such that if $|t-t_0|<\delta$ then $|f(t)-f(t_0)|<\epsilon$. By additivity of the measure, we have that if $p>q$ then $f(p)-f(q)=|f(p)-f(q)|=m(E_p-E_q)=m(A\cap (B_p(0)-B_q(0)))\leq V(p)-V(q)$, with the last inequality given by monotonicity. Choose $\delta$ so that if $|t-t_0|<\delta$, then $|V(t)-V(t_0)|<\epsilon$. Then $|f(t)-f(t_0)|<\epsilon$, so we are done.

Comment: Missed that. The edit above should work.

Comment: @MattS To apply the intermediate value theorem we do the following: $$0\leq a<m(A)\Rightarrow \exists E\subset A \text{ such that } m(E)=a$$ Is this correct?? At the inequality $0\leq a<m(A)$ the $0$ is the value of measure right??

Comment: Perhaps using $[-t,t]^d$ instead of $B_t(0)$ would make it easier to show continuity.

Comment: @MaryStar: It looks like you're just jumping directly to the conclusion without actually understanding what the hint suggests. What does the intermediate value theorem say? What do you apply it to here? What does it give you?

Comment: It's not necessary to exactly compute the area of the annulus. You just need to know that it approaches 0.

Comment: Ok!! I see... At an other exercise, it is $f(t)=m((-\infty ,t)\cap E)$ and I showed that $f$ is Lipschitz, so $f$ is continuous. To show the continuity in $\mathbb{R}^d$ could I also show that $f$ is Lipschitz?? But how??

Comment: @MattS Or do we show the continuity in an other way??

Comment: @Mary Star see edit.